# Find a formula for number of orbits under action of $D_{4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, dihedral-groups

> We colour each side of a square with $k \geq 1$ colours. Find a formula for the number of orbits under the action of $D_{4}=\{ e , r,r^{2},r^{3},s,sr,sr^{2},sr^{3} \}$ on the set of colours.

Now as far as I know an orbit of an element $a \in A$ under the action of group $G$  is defined as the set $ G \cdot a = \{ g \cdot a : g \in G\}$. In our case $A$ is the colouring of the square.

My attempt: Now if we number the sides of the square we can represent them as a set $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Now the generators of $G$ are $\langle r \rangle$ and $\langle s \rangle$. No matter the original state of the square $\langle r \rangle $ can only rotate it (by $90$ degrees), and thus the orbit then contains $4$ elements (since $r^{4}=e)$. Now this is also dependent on the amount of colours used (if $k=1$, then the orbit just contains the original square).

As you probably can tell, I don't really grasp the problem yet. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This kind of problems screams for the use of the [Cauchy-Frobenius lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma).

Comment: What exactly is meant by "We colour each side of a square with $k \geq 1$ colours"? Do they mean that we give each side a single color and that we have $k \geq 1$ colors to choose from?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins: I interpret that sentence the way you do. There is no furher elaboration on this part. But since each side is coloured by one of the $k\geq 1$ colours, I assume there are $k$ colours to choose from.

Comment: Then I don't see a way to avoid breaking into cases. What happens when $k = 1$ (trivial)? What happens when $k = 2$? Here I think there are $3$ cases not covered by the previous case. What happens when $k = 3$? I think there are $2$ distinct cases here not covered by the previous cases. What happens when $k = 4$? I think there's just one new case to consider here. Finally, when $k \geq 5$, we get no new cases.

Comment: I just realized it's possible I misinterpreted what they meant by side. By "side," do they mean "edge" or "face"?

Comment: I reckon they mean a edge by a side, but this too is ambiguous, I agree.